# middleware does not working laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to use **auth** middleware within my controller at construct method with **except** argument and it does not working.

I created my controller with artisan command and its contains methods like *create, edit, show*, etc.

here is my construct:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

if i visit some methods like edit and create when i'm not logged in middleware does not works and i can see the content. i also tried **only** instead of **except**, same result.

Comment: did you register your middleware in Kernel.php file's $routeMiddleware?

Comment: **auth** is one of the default middlewares, it's already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that problem was with my addressing/

i had **except** ***index*** and ***show*** at my *construct* and i was trying to access the edit method with */controller/edit* which is wrong, because controller assume the edit part as an **index** method argument, so i changed the url to */controller/1/edit* and it's working.

it was my bad, cause i used Codeigniter for a long time, sometimes i still think that i'm working with Ci.

Answer (score 0):

did you change Authenticate.php for auth middleware this function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
}
```

Comment: no i did not touch it, if i don't pass the second argument it works fine, but i don't want to run auth in all methods...

Comment: go to this middleware folder,then you got this file.Change it as your own way.